# Server Connection error between Opengts server and cell phone

Tags: opengts

I successfully installed openGTS and tested it with my cell phone using celltrackGTS app.  Everything worked great for 2 days....

Now I am getting a "Server Connection error" on the cell phone.  I've looked at the opengts logs and didn't see any errors related to this issue.

Does anyone have an idea as to what would cause the above error? And more importantly, a solution for the error

Answer (score 0):

Try to check OpenGTS port to see if it's accessible from Internet:
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: Thanks for the link... The port check shows my port is open

Answer (score 0):

Just, try to see your IP again, because if you have your IP automatic maybe your IP is different between the IP of the PC and the IP of the cellTracGTS.

Comment: This answer is more of a comment than an answer. Recommended reading: How to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

"Server Connection error" in celltrac app will appear for different reasons.

1) You might have entered a wrong URL or misspelled it.(Make sure its **"http://localhost:your_port/gprmc/Data"** not https.)

2) May be the GPS is'nt available. Probably you are under some heavy structures, check in clear sky conditions.

3) Same IMEA selected in celltrac app should be registered in opengts.(go to celltrac settings--> android ID or IMEI)

**NOTE :** To make sure gps values are getting into opengts server and all opengts configurations are proper just copy the below sample data format and change necessary params in browser and send

http://your_ip:port/gprmc/Data?ver=gtcfre-1.7.2&id=ur_mobile_IMEI&code=0xF010&time=present_epoch&lat=ur_lat&lon=ur_long&speed=10&head=0&alt=188&sat=3&hacc=12&batt=98&odom=95.26